# Why am I having "Invalid argument" while trying to accept connections?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

In the next code, while I try to connect a client the server shows the following error:

> "invalid argument", I can't see the error.

```
if((l_sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))!=-1)
{
    struct sockaddr_in srv_dir;

    srv_dir.sin_family=AF_INET;
    srv_dir.sin_port=8500;
    srv_dir.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;

    if((bind(l_sock,(struct sockaddr *)&srv_dir,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)))!=-1)
    {
        if(!(listen(l_sock,5)))
        {
            signal(SIGINT,cerraje);
            int t_sock;
            struct sockaddr_in cli_dir;
            socklen_t tam;
            time_t tstmp;
            struct tm * res;
            res=(struct tm *)malloc(sizeof(struct tm));

            while(!key)
            {
                if((t_sock=accept(l_sock,(struct sockaddr *)&cli_dir,&tam))!=-1)
                {
                    tstmp=time(&tstmp);
                    res=gmtime(&tstmp);
                    send(t_sock,res,sizeof(struct tm),0);
                    wr_hora(*res,cli_dir.sin_addr);         
                }
                else
                    perror("Petición no atendida");//The error is printed here.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read the documentation on [`accept(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept):

> The *addrlen* argument is a value-result argument: it should initially contain the size of the structure pointed to by *addr*; on return it will contain the actual length (in bytes) of the address returned. When *addr* is NULL nothing is filled in.

So you need to initialize the value of `tam` passed into `accept` with `sizeof(cli_dir)`.  You're fortunate that the socket library was able to catch your error, because you're passing in uninitialized memory, which results in undefined behavior.

Comment: That's it, thank you very much. I supposed that the variable tam was only an output value, so I don't even think that it needs an initial value.